# How to reassociate with Java library class after accidentally overriding

Tags: java, class, graphics

I'd really appreciate any help you can give me.  I did search around, but maybe I am using the wrong keywords...

Today I made the (very stupid) mistake of creating a new class file with the same name as a Java library class.  Specifically I called my class Graphics when I needed to use the Graphics class in AWT in the same program. So the program compiled with an error that it didn't recognize any of the methods I was calling from the awt.

I deleted my class and renamed it something valid, thinking that would restore the association with the awt class, but it didn't.  I did find 2 work-arounds:

1. using the specific import `java.awt.Graphics`; statement in addition to `import java.awt.*;`
2. using `java.awt.Graphics` instead of `Graphics` in any references in my programs (for example `public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g)`)

I would really like to find a permanent solution, however. This issue affected every program I have that references Graphics. Is there something I can do so that Java will reassociate the awt `Graphics` class?

I use JCreator and teach a beginning programming class in high school.

Comment: Have you tried recompiling? The environment might still be trying to refer to your class file.

Comment: Try maybe using other IDE like Eclipse which will let you rename your class in entire project.

Comment: Are you referring to just hitting the compile button again, or is recompiling something different?  I'm sorry if that's a really stupid question.  I did compile several times.  It will compile without errors and run with the work-arounds but not without.

Comment: @KPatterson Hmmm... What IDE are you using?

Comment: i could try NetBeans on my own computer, but my students only have JCreator so that is what we use in class.  @Pshemo

Comment: Did you try cleaning and building? Plus I think thats what he means by `recompiling`. Either way, `Clean and Build` is usually solution to such problems.

Comment: Oh yeah. You mentioned that... How did I not notice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to clear off any compiled forms of the Java source code, and start compiling it clean.

Basically, delete any `.class` files manually on the file system and recompile it using the new IDE. This should fix the problem.

Comment: Okay thank you all for your help!  I forgot to remove the compiled .class file before.  I swear my mind is not working today on only 2 hours of sleep...I don't feel very smart today!

Comment: Haha... Well, I'm glad I could help :D